# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, modulenotfounderror

I have installed both the packages already the icon and the core but still m getting this error, why??

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Nav.css';
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';

function Nav() {
    return ( 
        <div className = 'header' >
            <div className="header_left">
                <img className = 'header_image' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png' alt='' />
                <div className="header_search">
                    {/* Search icon */}
                    <SearchOutlinedIcon/>
                    <input type = 'text' placeholder='search' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Have you tried "npm install @mui/icons-material" ?

Comment: yes. I have tried it. in the terminal, it shows the installation has been successful, but the package.json doesn't show the module's name in it.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by changing
from

```js
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
```

to

```js
import { SearchOutlinedIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";
```

Comment: Note: to import from "@mui/icons-material" the import now is { SearchOutlined } and not { SearchOutlinedIcon } (note the lack of "Icon" suffix.

Comment: Same, but why? This only changed on a more recent version of `@mui/icons-material` for me, and only happens on some systems. I also believe the former way is better for bundle size. Do you have more information?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install also these packages.

// with npm

npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

// with yarn

yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Answer (score 1):

I had an exactly same problem to import icon from "@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlinedIcon" but it worked like this (below)

```
import { LightModeOutlinedIcon } from "@mui/icons-material"
```

or

```
import LightModeOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlined';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of details missing in the question but here's my take on it:

I'm using npm v7.24.1 at the moment and I have the same dependency listed in package.json

```
"@mui/icons-material": "5.2.0"
```

And it worked fine when I used it in a component like this

```
import { SearchOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
```

Reflecting on the comment under your question, which I cannot reply to unfortunately, are you sure you are running npm install in the same directory your package.json is located in? Because unless your npm version is less than 5, npm install @mui/icons-material must affect package.json (and package-lock.json). Use --save flag with npm install command if the version of your npm is less than 5. Verify npm version with "npm -v".

Another thing you could do is check whether @mui/icons-material exists inside node_modules folder. If not, try adding @mui/icons-material to the dependencies section of package.json manually and then run npm install in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Material UI version 4, your import statement should be as follows:

```js
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SearchOutlined';
```

Ensure that you do not mistakenly import it from @mui/icons-material, which is for Material UI version 5.

However, if you are using Material UI version 5, ensure that the required packages are installed by running the following command:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react
```

Once the packages are installed, you can import the icon as follows:

```js
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
```

This way, you'll have the correct import statements based on your Material UI version.